# Why is "drush make" installing a library in /sites/all/libraries instead of /libraries?

Tags: 8, drush

I am trying to allow prospective users to demo my module on simplytest.me, however, it requires an external javascript library. I recently created a drush make file for the D7 version of this module, and it is working fine. The D8 version is downloading the library, but placing it in drupalroot/sites/all/libraries instead drupalroot/libraries. Is there a way to change this behavior? Here is my make file.

```
api=2
core = 8.x
projects[drupal][type] = core
libraries[flot][download][type] = get
libraries[flot][download][url] = https://github.com/flot/flot/archive/master.zip
libraries[flot][destination] = libraries
libraries[flot][directory_name] = flot
```

I tried using `libraries[flot][destination] = /libraries` but that did not change the behavior.

Edit: I changed to a make.yml file, but this does not even download the library.

```
api: 2
core: 8.x
projects:
  - drupal
libraries:
  flot:
    destination: "libraries"
    directory_name: "flot"
    download:
      type: "get"
      url: "https://github.com/flot/flot/archive/master.zip"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drush status` tells me that I have version 5.10.0, so that's likely the issue. D8 support was not added until drush 8. Now I need to get upgraded.